# Is it required to encode values when using UploadString with C# WebClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have code like the following to do a POST to a server:

```
string URI = "http://mydomain.com/foo";
string myParameters =
   "&token=1234" +
   "&text=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(someVariable);

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
      wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
}
```

Is it required to UrlEncode the parameters like I'm doing or does `UploadString` handle that automatically under the covers? I don't want to risk any type of double encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is required to encode them if you use the `UploadString` method.

But you could use a more intelligent overload for your case ([`UploadValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx)):

```
string URI = "http://mydomain.com/foo";
var values = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "token", "1234" },
    { "text", someVariable },
};

using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] result = wc.UploadValues(URI, values);
    string htmlResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
}
```

Now you no longer need to worry about any encodings. The `WebClient` will take them into account when sending the request. Also you will notice that I have removed the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you were adding because when you use the `UploadValues` method this Content-Type header will automatically be added to the request.